# ASP.NET-Page very slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

my Asp.net page is very slow.
I try to trace but don't know how to read the outcome.

Can anyone help me please?

The problem:
Every time I clock on a link to load the site or hit F5 it needs ~ 2 seconds where nothing happens before the data / pics begin to load.

Comment: 1.your asp.net page is asp.net Web site or web project? 2. F5==Build or F5==Refresh Page in browser 3. can you provide some info about your data source.

Comment: F5 = Refresh. Its a Web Site.
Data Source = MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: This will happen if the App Pool is recycled and I've resolved this issue with simply code-behind, you can check here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc?noredirect=1#comment43136405_27339997](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369) add-on for Firerox. It is a cool tool that gives suggestions as of why your web page might be loading slowly.

Comment: very very nice, why can't every thing in the world be so easy

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to determine the cause or if it's just the build process, however one thing I will suggest is that you remote/disable elements of the page until you can determine the performance inhibitor.  You should also explore Tracing in ASP.NET:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210324184141/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/081501-1.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Is this on your local machine or once you've deployed?

The first time you hit a .net application, it needs to be "built", so the first time is always a bit slow.

Comment: Sorry, means F5 to refresh the site,